# PHP Date() strtotime get past month wrong

Tags: php

Current date is 30 October 2017

This code:

```
date("F",strtotime("-8 Month"))
```

Returns "March" where it should be February.

php snippet:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfba4f420e9f76026be0286b52d780d0a75b8cd3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers - I managed to solve it by using:

```
strtotime(date('Y-m')." -8 Month")
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that appears to be the case...

To get around that you could use...

```
echo date("F",strtotime("first day of -8 Month"));
```

That's from some discussion on http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because February has 28 or 29 days.
Use this hack and you will get the correct date

```
echo date("F",strtotime("first day of -8 Month"));
```

Comment: But won't this be incorrect if it's the first or second day of a month?

Comment: Edited, now. Gave the answer to fix 30th